# I install Primary-Remote on different networks ,But Cross cluster's pod access failure

Tags: docker, kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

I followed the [official documents](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/primary-remote_multi-network) to deploy two Kubernetes clusters and install istio  Primary-Remote on different networks.

I find that **the endpoints in the pod's outbound is the pod IP corresponding to the two clusters**, which seems to mean that cross-cluster communication requests do not flow into other clusters through the address gateway, which seems to be different from the network communication mode described in the official documents.

Who can tell me why and how to deal with it？

When installing is to cluster2, I made some changes to 'istiooperator' to meet the resource configuration. I use this command to export istio-eastwestgateway in cluster1.

```yaml
### cluster2's IstioOperator
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  profile: remote
  values:
    global:
      imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
      proxy:
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 0m
            memory: 40Mi
      meshID: mesh1
      multiCluster:
        clusterName: cluster2
      network: network2
      remotePilotAddress: 192.168.79.78
  components:
    ingressGateways:
    - name: istio-ingressgateway
      k8s:
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 0m
            memory: 40Mi
    pilot:
      k8s:
        env:
          - name: PILOT_TRACE_SAMPLING
            value: "100"
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 0m
            memory: 100Mi
```

```
### cluster2's eastwest-gateway
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  name: eastwest
spec:
  profile: empty
  components:
    ingressGateways:
      - name: istio-eastwestgateway
        label:
          istio: eastwestgateway
          app: istio-eastwestgateway
          topology.istio.io/network: network2
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "0m"
          env:
            # sni-dnat adds the clusters required for AUTO_PASSTHROUGH mode
            - name: ISTIO_META_ROUTER_MODE
              value: "sni-dnat"
            # traffic through this gateway should be routed inside the network
            - name: ISTIO_META_REQUESTED_NETWORK_VIEW
              value: network2
          service:
            ports:
              - name: status-port
                port: 15021
                targetPort: 15021
              - name: mtls
                port: 15443
                targetPort: 15443
              - name: tcp-istiod
                port: 15012
                targetPort: 15012
              - name: tcp-webhook
                port: 15017
                targetPort: 15017
  values:
    global:
      #jwtPolicy: first-party-jwt
      meshID: mesh1
      network: network2
      multiCluster:
        clusterName: cluster2
```

After the installation of the two clusters, when I followed the [document for verification](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/verify/), I found that the pods between different clusters could not communicate normally. The results of cross-cluster communication are as follows

```
[root@localhost k8s_ctx]# kubectl exec --context="${CTX_CLUSTER1}" -n sample -c sleep \
>     "$(kubectl get pod --context="${CTX_CLUSTER1}" -n sample -l \
>     app=sleep -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}')" \
>     -- curl helloworld.sample:5000/hello
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    60  100    60    0     0    674      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   674
Hello version: v1, instance: helloworld-v1-5897696f47-5lsqp
[root@localhost k8s_ctx]# 
[root@localhost k8s_ctx]# 
[root@localhost k8s_ctx]# kubectl exec --context="${CTX_CLUSTER1}" -n sample -c sleep     "$(kubectl get pod --context="${CTX_CLUSTER1}" -n sample -l \
    app=sleep -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}')"     -- curl helloworld.sample:5000/hello
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    84  100    84    0     0      8      0  0:00:10  0:00:10 --:--:--    22
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: local reset
```

This my clusters info and

```
[root@localhost istio-1.8.1]# istioctl version
client version: 1.8.1
control plane version: 1.8.1
data plane version: 1.8.1 (8 proxies)
```

```
[root@localhost istio-1.8.1]# istioctl pc endpoint  sleep-854565cb79-77lt7 --port 5000 
ENDPOINT                 STATUS      OUTLIER CHECK     CLUSTER
192.167.102.190:5000     HEALTHY     OK                outbound|5000||helloworld.sample.svc.cluster.local
192.169.169.7:5000       HEALTHY     OK                outbound|5000||helloworld.sample.svc.cluster.local

[root@localhost istio-1.8.1]# kubectl --context cluster1 get po -o wide 
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP                NODE                    NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
helloworld-v1-5897696f47-5lsqp   2/2     Running   0          73m   192.167.102.190   localhost.localdomain   <none>           <none>
sleep-854565cb79-77lt7           2/2     Running   0          73m   192.167.102.130   localhost.localdomain   <none>           <none>
[root@localhost istio-1.8.1]# kubectl --context cluster2 get po -o wide 
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP               NODE         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
helloworld-v2-7bbf4994d7-k577f   2/2     Running   0          73m   192.169.169.7    node-79-79   <none>           <none>
sleep-8f795f47d-74qgz            2/2     Running   0          73m   192.169.169.21   node-79-79   <none>           <none>
```